# Eclipse Installation Error

Tags: eclipse

Here's the error log:

```
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.mars
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.3.0.v20151219-1433, build=2066, branch=1b2f4988d30b5488639792252f724cb1b1634703, commit=1b2f4988d30b5488639792252f724cb1b1634703
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.3.0.v20151219-1325, build=2066, branch=1b2f4988d30b5488639792252f724cb1b1634703, commit=1b2f4988d30b5488639792252f724cb1b1634703
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.3.0.v20151221-1559, build=2066, branch=1b2f4988d30b5488639792252f724cb1b1634703, commit=1b2f4988d30b5488639792252f724cb1b1634703
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Mars))
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Offline = false
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Mirrors = true
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Resolving 5 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Eclipse\java-mars\eclipse
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Requirement epp.package.java [4.5.0,4.6.0)
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.5.0,4.6.0)
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.5.0,4.6.0)
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group [3.11.0,3.12.0)
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/201510021000
[2016-01-09 10:47:00] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2016-01-09 10:47:04] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2016-01-09 10:47:06] Computing prerequisite plan
[2016-01-09 10:47:13] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2016-01-09 10:47:13] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2016-01-09 10:47:13] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2016-01-09 10:47:13] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2016-01-09 10:47:15] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2016-01-09 10:47:15] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:524)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:329)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3028)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2957)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2938)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2829)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1189)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$28(SimpleVariablePage.java:1066)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$19.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1011)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Eclipse_java-mars_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3028)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2957)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2938)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2829)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1189)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$28(SimpleVariablePage.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$19.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1011)

[2016-01-09 10:47:15]
```

I was trying to install Eclipse Mars using the Eclipse Installer (download page [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/mars/R1a/eclipse-inst-win64.exe)). I'm using Windows 10, 64 bit. I have tried running the installer exe as an administrator, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I've also tried downloading the installer from other mirrors, yet my problem remains the same.

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: I've included it in the post.
`ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the eclipse community here is it, it  sounds like perhaps something was downloaded from a mirror with a bad artifact. When I had strange errors like this(that look like bad artifacts), I generally go back in the wizard, turn off the use of mirrors, and try again.

Comment: So, I downloaded the installer from their main download site, and now it's successful. The link was at the bottom of the page so, I didn't take notice immediately.